# DocumentElement.SelectNodes returns null (Html Agility Pack)

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I just need to parse through a table in html, which looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>
  </title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
  ***contents***
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

My code looks like this:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(@path);
foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
{
  foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
  {
    foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td"))
    {
      ***copy content***
    }
  }
}
```

But then I get NullReferenceException at

```
foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
```

So table doesn't have anything in it, but why?

Comment: Is it empty in the table node as well or just the rows ? as you dont have any tr's in your HTML ?

Comment: Sorry, the exception occurs at the first foreach statement, but I do have tr's, just didn't show them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've fixed it. The problem was the **LoadHtml** method, which takes an html string as a parameter. For a file **Load** should be used.

Comment: This realy isnt an answer. I have exactly the same problem (xpath which may or may not exists, throwing null reference exception) and this is not even close to be a solution to your own question.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've been lying to myself and others because I want attention.

Comment: No need for hard feeling - it just happened i have exactly the same problem and cant find solution. And this question is first on google search "html agility pack SelectNodes returns null".

Answer (score 1):

As you dont have any tr's table rows in your HTML the agility pack is not finding any

```
 try this 
            // Get all tables in the document
            HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");

            // Iterate all rows in the first table
            HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[0].SelectNodes(".//tr");
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i)
            {


            }
```

Comment: I do, I just didn't want to clutter the code. But that wouldn't even matter, since the exception occurs in the first foreach statement, before any mention of tr/td/dh.

Comment: And I have tried this way, but since tables is still null, accessing tables[0] gives me the same exception.